# How to handle popups in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

how to handle the popup and access the popup to do some operations on it.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await page.click(Launchpopup);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

So what I do is I login to facebook on their homepage, then navigate to the page I want to go to where the sign in with facebook button is I click on it. And then this code below will once the popup happens click on the login with facebook button.

```js
await page.click('[service_name="facebook"]')
const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page()))); 
const popup = await newPagePromise;
await popup.waitForSelector('[name="__CONFIRM__"]')
const confirm = await popup.$('[name="__CONFIRM__"]')
await popup.click('[name="__CONFIRM__"]')
await page.waitFor(2000);
await page.goto('your login page'); $
```

Answer (score 10):

Since version 0.13.0, you can use the following code:

```
... code to open popup...
const pages = await browser.pages(); // get all open pages by the browser
const popup = pages[pages.length - 1]; // the popup should be the last page opened
```

Comment: Not working with puppeteer@1.14.0, only @luneth777 works

Answer (score 7):

This code is Typescript, but you get the idea:

```
async function waitForPopupMatching(
  browser: Puppeteer.Browser,
  regex: RegExp,
  openAction: () => Promise<void>,
  timeout: number = 30000,
): Promise<Puppeteer.Page> {
  const promise = new Bluebird<Puppeteer.Target>(resolve => {
    const listener = async (target: Puppeteer.Target) => {
      if (target.type() === 'page' && regex.test(target.url())) {
        browser.removeListener('targetcreated', listener);
        resolve(target);
      }
    };
    browser.addListener('targetcreated', listener);
  }).timeout(timeout);

  await openAction(); // Typically a mouse click

  const tgt = await promise;
  return await tgt.page();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the documentation for v0.12.0-alpha, it describes how to interact with dialogs.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    console.log(dialog.message());
    await dialog.dismiss();
    await browser.close();
  });
  page.evaluate(() => alert('1'));
});
```

Relevant [docs can be found here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-dialog).

Comment: Yeah I am able to interact with dialogs but how do I handle popup's

Comment: Are you talking about popups that are not native to the browser, but generated using html and css?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear yeah I was talking about pop up windows

Comment: Has a solution been found?

Comment: @Kaelinator No I believe.

Comment: This worked to get the text and focus. I'm now working on hitting the OK button but you got me going so thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

Puppeteer popup event

Starting with puppeteer version 1.12, a special ‘popup’ event has been added to the page, which allows you to catch new tabs and popups. We use it by rewriting the first example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');         // puppeteer

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();       // run browser
const page = await browser.newPage();           // open new tab
await page.goto('https://example.com');            // go to site.com       

await page.waitForSelector('#goto');            // wait object load
const link = await page.$('#goto');             // declare object

const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => page.once('popup', x));

await link.click();                        // click, a new tab  opens
const newPage = await newPagePromise; 
await newPage.close();             // close it, for example
await browser.close();                          // close browser
```