# Is there any way to close popup while running headless chromium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

I am using the Playwright library to get data from a website. The issue is that website shows a popup when it open which results in stuck processes since the program is not able to get any button due to the popup.

Is there any way to close a popup each time it appears using the playwright?

Edit:

Page is creating a pop-up. I inspect the page and learnt that they are not using the modal for the pop instead they wrote the inline css and decorated a div as the popup.

Comment: When you say popup, do you mean a separate window? Or just a modal that is overlaying the page in the current window?

Comment: @EelkevandenBos, a model which overlaying the page in the current window.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect a strategy to close modals.

Comment: It might be helpful to clarify whether you mean the page is creating its own modal/popup or it's using the browser's built-in [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) function.

Answer (score 1):

**Closing actual popups**

I think `browser.once("targetcreated", ...)` as described in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/57246544/2202112 could be something that you are looking for.

It allows you to setup a callback on newly created targets.

For reference, see puppeteer [docs on "targetcreated"](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/#:%7E:text=Emitted%20when%20a%20target%20is%20created%2C%20for%20example%20when%20a%20new%20page%20is%20opened%20by%20window.open%20or%20browser.newPage.)

**Closing modals**

1. Find the selector for the button that dismisses the modal, for example `.button-close` or `.button-dismiss`.
2. Use the `page.click(selector, [options])` method to click the button before continuing further scraping

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/dialogs#alert-confirm-prompt-dialogs) says Playwright will automatically dismiss all modal dialogs if there are no listeners of `"dialog"` event. Default behavior is essentially equivalent to

```
page.on('dialog', dialog => dialog.dismiss());
```

if it doesn't close in your case, it's most likely not a modal dialog (or a bug in playwright).

If the page opens another popup page, you can follow [this guide](https://playwright.dev/docs/multi-pages#handling-popups) but from your description it sounds more like a modal dialog.

Comment: You are right, but somehow the popup is not closed by default in my case, any idea?

Comment: It might be a bug, you can file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues with a repro so that we can have a look.